# Rails 5: partial view with condition and locals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, partial-views, locals

I'm a bit lost in creating "New campaign" button if user has particular role.

In models/roles.rb I have:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user, optional: true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user

  enum general: { seller: 1, buyer: 2, seller_buyer: 3}, _suffix: true
  enum dashboard: { denied: 0, viewer: 1, editer: 2, creater: 3, deleter: 4}, _suffix: true
```

In controllers/dashboards_controller.rb I have:

```
def dashboard_1 
@roles = current_user.roles
  if @roles.any? { |role| role.creater_dashboard? || role.deleter_dashboard? }
    flash.now[:error] = "You are creater/deleter!"
  elsif @roles.any? { |role| role.viewer_dashboard? }
    flash.now[:error] = "You are viewer!"
  else 
    redirect_to users_path
  end
end
```

I have partial campaigns/_new.html.erb like this:

```
<li>
<%= link_to new_campaign_path(@campaign), {method: 'get', class: 'btn btn-w-m btn-primary'} do %>New campaign
<% end %>
</li>
```

and in dashboards/dashboard_1.html.erb I would need to **render "New campaign" button if user is "creater" of "deleter" for Dashboard**:

```
<% if ... %>
<%= render partial: "campaigns/new" %>
```

As I have found out it can be done with locals, however I cannot figure out how? Many thanks for any help!

**Added**

In layouts/application.html.erb I have this:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
     <%= render 'layouts/navigation' %>
```

and in partial _navigation.html.erb I have this:

```
<li class="<%= is_active_controller('dashboards') %>">
<% if @creator_deleter %>
   <%= link_to dashboard_path do %>
   <i class="fa fa-th-large"></i> <span class="nav-label" data-i18n="nav.dashboard">Dashboard</span>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
 </li>
... #other links to different parts of app
```

How to hide "dashboard" link in partial if user is not @creator_deleter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't render the form with locals from the controller. Is there any reason why you would want to use a local? - these are normally used when rendering partials to pass local variables from one view to the partial, for purposes of reuse. for example...

```
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { my_local_var: my_local_var } %>
```

I think what you actually want to do is set an instance variable from within the controller that is accessible during the rendering process. For example...

```
if @roles.any? { |role| role.creater_dashboard? || role.deleter_dashboard? }
  @creator_deleter = true
elsif @roles.any? { |role| role.viewer_dashboard? }
    @viewer = true
else 
  redirect_to users_path
end
```

and then you can test for that in your view

```
<% if @creator_deleter %>
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right and thank you for solution! I did not realize I should do `@creator_deleter = true` thing :)

Comment: Please, can you check my code added above where I have partial _navigation.html.erb ? How do I make link_to dashboard hide if user is not @creator_deleter ? Many thanks for any help!

Comment: simply don't render it i.e. <% if @creater_deleter %><%= link_to .... %><% end %>

Comment: Probably I did not put it right. I have several links in navigation bar, which is _navigation.html.erb  If user is not @creator_deleter it should not see dashboard link. I was thinking there has to be some way to not rendering particular part of partial. Or I am wrong? `<% if @creator_deleter %>` in partial file is not working.

Comment: If I understand correctly the rendering of the link is conditional based on the @creater_deleter flag. In what way doesn't my suggestion give you that?

Comment: Well, _navigation.html.erb is partial gloably for the whole app. If I plave `@creator_deleter` there, it is not working properly. Basically if does not check that user is `@creator_deleter` and hides link to dashboard for any user.

Comment: I would also suggest rather than editing your existing question into a different one you should be posting a new question. My accepted answer is irrelevant and confusing now to anyone looking at this and doesn't add any value to StackOverflow.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'll create new question.

Comment: No it will only hide it for current_user. The page isn't just rendered once and static to all requests coming in. It's rendered each time you hit your server with a request (unless you are using AJAX too, which I don't believe you are)

Comment: actually i realised the original question is intact so its ok ... but still :)

Comment: ok, so basically I have to start implementing AJAX in order to have `@creator_deleter` working in partial? You got me, I am absolute beginner :)